# What is the word to describe a person who does not have a personal opinion?

Tags: single-word-requests, nonsubjective

What is the word to describe a person who does not have a personal opinion or stand on a subject?

If somebody says X is right, then you could agree. But if some other person says X is wrong, and you also agree, you are not really expressing your own opinion. You are simply agreeing with everyone else. How do you describe that kind of personality with one word in a formal way? Specifically, someone who cannot make decisions on their own and depends on others' opinions.

Comment: There are any number of possible answers. *Neutral, undecided, diplomatic, flip-flopper, inattentive, forgetful, willing to learn from mistakes* and a hundred more. You will have to be way more specific. Do they really not *have* an opinion, or do they just *withhold* it; for what reason and to what end do they act like that; do they always do that, or in particular situations, or just once; is it considered a good thing or a bad thing, and considered by whom. And so on and so forth.

Comment: Since it has not yet been mentioned, I'll add *ambivalent*. It does not imply indifference, but it does imply an inability or refusal to decide definitively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One who doesn't take a stance on a subject can be characterized as ***impartial*** or ***indifferent***

> **impartial** (adj) - treating all rivals or disputants equally; fair and just:
>
> **indifferent** (adj) - having no particular interest or sympathy; unconcerned*

One who can't make decisions on his own is certainly [***diffident***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/diffident):

> adj - lacking confidence in one's own ability, worth, or fitness; timid; shy.

There are many options though. You should be more specific and maybe provide some context:  *apathetic, infirm, weak-willed, detached, aloof* are all terms that spring to mind.

Medically speaking, a person who can't make his own decisions and constantly depends on others suffers from [Dependent Personality Disorder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_personality_disorder).

*New Oxford American Dictionary**

Answer (score 3):

Some of the following nouns and adjectives may apply.
• *[wishy-washy](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wishy-washy#Adjective)*, “Wavering; lacking in commitment, certainty, or support; namby-pamby.”
• *[yes man](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yes_man#Noun)* (or *[yes-man](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yes-man#Noun)*), “(idiomatic) A person who always agrees with his employer or superior.”
• *[yeasayer](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yeasayer#Noun)*, “(pejorative) One who habitually agrees uncritically.”
• *[weathercock](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/weathercock#Noun)*, “(figuratively) One who veers with every change of current opinion; a fickle, inconstant person.”
• *[fickle](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fickle#Adjective)*, “Quick to change one’s opinion or allegiance; insincere; not loyal or reliable.”

Answer (score 2):

Consider *meek*.

> [meek](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/meek): evidencing little spirit or courage; overly submissive or compliant

Answer (score 1):

That person is a **[sheep](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sheep)**.

> a person who is too easily influenced or led.
>
> "the party members had become sheep, and she refused to be taken in"

Answer (score -2):

I would say that this person is **agreeable**

Comment: Hmm. I think 'agreeable' carries a positive connotation, rather than the negative meaning meant by OP.