# Word for a person with the same opinion on everything?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a person I know who has the same opinion on everything. It never wavers from "very good" e.g.

> That was a very good movie
>
> Brazil played a very good game
>
> The weather was very good yesterday

They're not really an optimist per se, as a term such as the one I'm looking for could easily apply to someone with the opposite "very bad" opinion of everything.

What I'm wondering is there a particular term for someone who has the same opinion on everything?

---

This is a [similar (but not the same) question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174524/what-is-the-word-to-describe-a-person-who-does-not-have-a-personal-opinion), and although some of the answers here (such as yeasayer) could work in certain contexts, they don't fully answer my question.

Comment: Right. There ought to be a word for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a somewhat broad phrase, **[Johnny one-note](https://www.wordnik.com/words/Johnny-one-note)** (or *one-note Johnny*), that covers repetitive views beyond simple affect

> An opinion or viewpoint on a single subject or a few particular subjects which is frequently expressed by a person or organization

It derives from the song, "[Johnny One Note](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Johnny-one-note)", in a Broadway musical

> a show tune from the 1937 Rodgers and Hart musical Babes in Arms. The lyrics tell a story of a male vocalist named Johnny who sang with a band and could sing only one note, but sang that note extremely well.

The person you describe is an *emotional Johnny one-note*.

It's a bit less colorful, but you could simply use the term **[one-note](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/one-note)**

> unvarying in tone or emphasis :  monotonous

Answer (score 1):

I was going to post it as a comment, but looking at the definition in Urban Dictionary, it could be closer to what you want then I thought.

[*One Trick Pony*](http://gog.is/define+one+trick+pony) - used to describe a friend, acquaintance or stranger, who has very few talents, sayings, jokes or skills. [<sub>Definition on Urban Dictionary</sub>](http://www.urbandictionary.com/thesaurus.php?term=one+trick+pony)

> "You're such a one trick pony!"

Comment: A variation of this could definitely be a goer. "A one-comment pony"?